# C initialize array in hexadecimal values

Tags: c, arrays, string, hex, unsigned

I would like to initialize a 16-byte array of hexadecimal values, particularly the 0x20 (space character) value.

What is the correct way?

```
unsigned char a[16] = {0x20};
```

or

```
unsigned char a[16] = {"0x20"};
```

Thanks

Comment: `0x2` is not the space character, but an integer.

Comment: I am talking about the ASCII space character in hex, which is `0x20`

Comment: The C standard does not use ASCII. (Just noted I missed a trailing `0`; I meant `0x20`, of course). If you mean space, you should use a space character constant: `' '`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a GNU extension called [designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).
This is enabled by default with `gcc`

With this you can initialize your array in the form

```
unsigned char a[16] = {[0 ... 15] = 0x20};
```

Comment: Designated initialisers are not a gcc extension, but standard C.  Allowing a range is an extension, however is..

Answer (score 8):

Defining this, for example

```
unsigned char a[16] = {0x20, 0x41, 0x42, };
```

will initialise the first three elements as shown, and the remaining elements to `0`.

Your second way

```
unsigned char a[16] = {"0x20"};
```

won't do what you want: it just defines a nul-terminated string with the four characters `0x20`, the compiler won't treat it as a hexadecimal value.

Comment: Ahh ok I see. And what if I want the ASCII value of 0x20? Like I want the keyboard space that that hex value gives.

Comment: @Kingamere the ASCII value ***is*** 0x20 (hex) or 32 (decimal). If you print that as an `int` you'll get `32` and if you print as `char` you'll get ` ` (space).

Answer (score 5):

```
unsigned char a[16] = {0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20};
```

or

```
unsigned char a[16] = "\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20";
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is what you were looking for, but if the size of the given array is going to be changed (frequently or not), for easier maintenance you may consider the following method based on *[memset()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memset.htm)*

```
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_OF_CHARS 16

int main()
{
    unsigned char a[NUM_OF_CHARS];

    // initialization of the array a with 0x20 for any value of NUM_OF_CHARS
    memset(a, 0x20, sizeof(a));

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first way is correct, but you need to repeat the `0x20,` sixteen times. You can also do this:

```
unsigned char a[16] = "                ";
```

Comment: This solution will lead to undefined behavior! *`"<16 spaces>"`* will actually occupy 17 bytes (the last one for '\0').

Comment: @AlexLop. Negative, the C specification allows a character array to be initialized using a string literal that is the same size as the array. In that case the NUL terminator is dropped.

Comment: Could you please point me to the documentation which will support your statement?

Comment: Section 6.7.9 paragraph 14, which says (emphasis added):
*"Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character **if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array."*

Comment: You are right, my mistake. Could you please make a small edit in your answer so I could "undo" the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `memset`.

No need to type out anything and the size of the array is only provided once at initialisation.

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned char b[16];
  memset(b, 0x20, sizeof(b));
}
```